# CSS position (tabbless) and removing (hiding) empty DIVS

Tags: css, positioning

I'm having some trouble getting this done 'right'...

its a two parter. :)

1.) is getting the layout to look like how I need it (without resorting to tables!), but for some reason I can get the divs and nested divs to 'act right'... (surely its my error/mis-understanding)

I am trying to get a layout like so, using only DIVS and display..etc..

http://dmstudios.net/misc/layout.jpg

I have attempted it myself (so you dont think Im just looking for a handout) :)..
but some things like the vertical alignment of the custom div container isnt working..etc

Here is my JSFiddle attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/yeKxU/1/

JSFiddle Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://academickids.com/encyclopedia/images/thumb/5/53/150px-Blue_morpho_butterfly_300x271.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="custom">
        <div class="president">item1</div>
        <div class="mission">item2</div>
        <div class="active">item3</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="url">www.nike.com</div>
    <div class="freetext">random text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
border: 1px dashed blue;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

div{
    display: inline-block;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:2px;
    border-color:#FF0000;    
}

.container{
    width:450px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.logo{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.custom{
    vertical-align:top; /* doesnt work to move the 'custom div' to the top */
/* width:63%;*/  /*needs to auto stretch to fit the rest of the space after image*/
}

.custom div{    
    display:block;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}

.url{
    width:100%;
}

.freetext{    
    width:100%;
}
```

Couple notes: the '3' fields to the right of the image div, will have varying data in them.. (meaning I am not clear if they will need to wrap or not...hopefully not a problem)

The second portion of the question, is about implementing some dynamic capabilities. (jQuery I imagine should work)..

2.) Knowing the general (perfect scenario) layout I am trying to achieve above...
I need to also code things in a way.. that is certain parts of the data are MISSING, then that 'cell' (div) is removed/hidden (or something)

*(I am building this using PHP printed to screen, to spit out the HTML/DIVS..etc  and using variables to populate the content of the DIV/image..etc)

So for example..

- if the IMAGE was not there (variable is empty)..  Id like the the CUSTOM div that has 3 child divs in it 1 for each of the text fields) to expand all thew way to the LEFT.. as the logo/image DIV will have nothing (or be removed/hidden since its empty)
- Same goes for the text fields in the CUSTOM DIV container.. if one of those fields are BLANK... its should NOT just have a blank/empty placeholder...  it should be removed/hidden.. and the rest of the data butted up to the TOP (under any other fields that may be present)

I've seen examples (sorta) where you have some DIV blocks on the stage.. click on one.. it removes it.. the other DIVS move over...etc...  (sorta the same thing, except I cant manually click things to remove them)..

So maybe some jQuery to go through the 'DIVS' see if its empty and then remove itself?

-or-

would just having some sort of layout that is fluid/liquid work? be better? so I dont really need to check if its empty.. if nothing is IN the cell/DIV.. then the other just adjust their WIDTH/POSITION to make-up for it?

Let me know what you guys think?  JSFiddle examples are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Protip: If you have to write that much to get your question(s) out, you're probably asking too much for one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the layout in question one you do like this...

```
#divA {float:left;}
#divB {float:left;}
```

before divC you can put an empty div (id="empty") like this...

```
#empty {clear:both;}
```

this should fix the design, assuming you have your width seth on the divs...

for question 2 i suggest you create the divs dynamically, when you create your content on page... if you want examples, just let me know...

Comment: thanks for the (real) reply...
Question: if I am not sure how WIDE the image is going to be in DIV A..    how can I set widths for DIV A & B? (they need to sorta be fluid) but also be displayed in-line (visually) If the image in DIV A is 50px wide.. I want DIV B to take up the rest of the slack/room..   if the image in DIV A is 150px wide.. I want DIV B to 'shrink' a little and take up the rest of the 450px space that is left.   Hope that makes sense?..

Comment: previous post: 


 
ok, been playing with it more.. but cant seem to get things to 'work'... specifically if you click on the image/logo.. (it removes it through some jQuery) but the other 'custom div' container does NOT 'max out' on width using the above max-width approach? Here is my latest 'fiddle': jsfiddle.net/yeKxU/5 Is there no way to take up the rest of the 'width' WHEN an image IS present? and then use 100% of the width when an image is NOT Present? Appreciate the help! Thanks –

--does this mean its NOT possible to have this sorta fluid layout?  Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of properties you can set on your divs, one is max-width... one risk of not setting any value on width on your divs is that if your total width get wider than your holding container your divB will stack up under divA... and i think you dont want that to happen... :) you can do some experiments with min-width and max-width on your divs to get the behavior you want because i guess you have some values on your pic to play with...

```
divA {
    float:left;
    max-width:50px;
}

divB {
    float:left;
    min-width:400px;
}
```

as example, you have to find your values, trial and error-way i guess...

there is also a lot of guides on internet if you search on css and positioning... happy hunting!

Comment: ok, been playing with it more.. but cant seem to get things to 'work'...  specifically if you click on the image/logo.. (it removes it through some jQuery) but the other 'custom div' container does NOT 'max out' on width using the above max-width approach?

Here is my latest 'fiddle': http://jsfiddle.net/yeKxU/5/ 

Is there no way to take up the rest of the 'width' WHEN an image IS present?  and then use 100% of the width when an image is NOT Present?  Appreciate the help!  

Thanks